# Retrieving a value from a C# DataLibrary to be placed in ASP.Net label

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have a DataClassLibrary attached to my ASP.Net project. I use it to access the database to get my values. I want to take the values given in the Line1 class and put them in the corresponding label. I tried DataLibraryClass.Line1 NewDataA = new DataLibraryClass.Line1(); but it gives me a zero I know that they have values. Could it be that my NewDataA = new is causing it to return zero? I also used breakpoints in the Line1 class and it never reaches the database query. How can I get the data I need into the labels properly?

DataLibraryClass
Line1:

```
 var sqlString = new StringBuilder();
 sqlString.Append("SELECT CaseNum6, CaseNum9, Group, Completion ");
 sqlString.Append("FROM WorkOrder ");
 sqlString.Append("WHERE Group = 1 OR Group = 2 ");
 sqlString.Append("AND Completion = 0 ");

 SqlDataReader reader = null;
 SqlConnection dbConn = DBHelper.getConnection();
 SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@CaseNum6", CaseNum6 )};

    try
    {
        reader = DBHelper.executeQuery(dbConn, sqlString.ToString(), parameters);
        if (reader != null)
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                CaseNum6 = (int)reader["CaseNum6"];
                CaseNum9 = (int)reader["CaseNum9"];
                Group = (int)reader["Group"];
                Completion = (bool)reader["Completion"];
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("No record returned");
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            dbConn.Close();
            dbConn.Dispose();
```

DataLibraryClass
DBHelper:

```
private DBHelper() { }

public static SqlConnection getConnection()
{
    return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
}

public static SqlConnection getFRESHConnection()
{
   return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FRESHConnection"].ConnectionString);
 }

public static SqlDataReader executeQuery(SqlConnection dbConn, string sqlString, SqlParameter[] parameters)
 {
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        if (dbConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            dbConn.Open();
        cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sqlString;
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        }
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return reader;
```

Code behind ASP page:

```
DataClassLibrary.LineAData NewDataA = new DataClassLibrary.LineAData();
DataClassLibrary.LineBData NewDataB = new DataClassLibrary.LineBData();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    L1.Text = NewDataA.CaseNum6.ToString();
    L2.Text = NewDataA.CaseNum9.ToString();

    L4.Text = NewDataB.CaseNum6.ToString();
    L5.Text = NewDataB.CaseGNum9.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is the code that accesses the database called in a LineAData() method? You don't show enough of that class to truly diagnose the problem (the methods and properties). On a side note, used stored procedures instead of writing the query as a string inside your class. Plus, you're passing a parameter into the query that doesn't have any parameters defined.

Comment: did you look into Asp.net Repeaters control? if you want to do it without repeaters, why don't you Create Public/Protected variables, assign them values in code-behind, and show them within your aspx pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon setting up the webpage I failed to realize the behind code was set to .vb not .cs which is why everything was not working.